# Roll max in R. From first row to current row

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I would like to calculate max value from first row to current row

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2), value = c(2,5,3,2,4,5,4), result = c(NA,2,5,5,NA,4,5))
```

I have tried grouping by id with dplyr and using rollmax function from zoo but did not success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** rollmax is used with a fixed width but here we have a variable width so using rollapplyr, which seems close to the approach of the question, we have:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(out = lag(rollapplyr(value, 1:n(), max))) %>%
 ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id value result   out
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     NA    NA
2     1     5      2     2
3     1     3      5     5
4     1     2      5     5
5     2     4     NA    NA
6     2     5      4     4
7     2     4      5     5
```

**2)** It is also possible to perform the grouping via the width (second) argument of rollapplyr like this eliminating dplyr.  In this case the widths are 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3 and Max is like max except it does not use the last element of its argument x.  (An alternate expression for the width would be seq_along(id) - match(id, id) + 1).

```
library(zoo)

Max <- function(x) if (length(x) == 1) NA else max(head(x, -1))
transform(df, out = rollapplyr(value, sequence(rle(id)$lengths), Max))
```

giving:

```
  id value result out
1  1     2     NA  NA
2  1     5      2   2
3  1     3      5   5
4  1     2      5   5
5  2     4     NA  NA
6  2     5      4   4
7  2     4      5   5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(result = lag(cummax(value)))

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   id [2]
#      id value result
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1     2     NA
# 2     1     5      2
# 3     1     3      5
# 4     1     2      5
# 5     2     4     NA
# 6     2     5      4
# 7     2     4      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.  This would just get you the cumulative maximum:

```
df$result = ave(df$value, df$i, FUN=cummax)
```

To get the cumulative maximum with the lag you wanted:

```
df$result = ave(df$value, df$i, FUN=function(x) c(NA,cummax(x[-(length(x))])))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `shift` + `cummax`

```
> setDT(df)[, result2 := shift(cummax(value)), id][]
   id value result result2
1:  1     2     NA      NA
2:  1     5      2       2
3:  1     3      5       5
4:  1     2      5       5
5:  2     4     NA      NA
6:  2     5      4       4
7:  2     4      5       5
```